# ¿Qué hacer cuando me doy cuenta que mi respuesta es incorrecta y otra persona ya contestó correctamente?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Imaginemos la situación siguiente:

Alguien hace una pregunta, y yo le doy una respuesta. Después de un tiempo, a pesar de recibir votos a favor (como a menudo sucede tristemente), me doy cuenta que mi respuesta es incorrecta (tal vez me doy cuenta por mi propia cuenta, tal vez alguien me deja un comentario, tal vez me doy cuenta por los votos negativos que recibo, etc...). Por supuesto, ahora decido modificar mi respuesta para que sea correcta.

Sin embargo, sea antes o después de corregir mi respuesta, me doy cuenta que alguien más entre tanto dejó una buena respuesta a la pregunta.

**¿Cuál es el proceder aceptable/recomendable en esta situación?**

1. Borrar mi respuesta, y votar a favor de la otra respuesta
2. Corregir mi respuesta aunque ahora quede básicamente igual a la otra respuesta, pero por lo menos voto a favor de la otra respuesta.
3. Corregir mi respuesta aunque ahora quede básicamente igual a la otra respuesta, y no votar a favor de la otra respuesta para poder competir mejor con ella, sobre todo que ya tengo algunos votos a favor (quien sabe porque...) y además es más probable que siga recibiendo votos a favor por haber sido el primero en contestar.
4. ¿Otra opción?

Hago la pregunta porque a menudo veo que los usuarios escogen las opciones 2 o 3. A mí me parece mejor la primera opción.

¿Cómo lo manejan ustedes? ¿Han notado lo mismo? ¿Qué hacen cuando notan que alguien no maneja la situación de la manera que ustedes piensan que se debería?

Answer (score 5):

Esta es una cuestión muy interesante cuya respuesta puede tener muchos matices.

Recordemos que estamos diez-quince minutos contestando una respuesta y luego tenemos muchos años por delante para que esta sea de utilidad a la gente que la encuentre. Si en el futuro alguien entra y ve dos respuestas iguales, de poco le servirán. Ahora bien, si ve que tienen pequeños matices que las enriquecen seguro que aprenderá mucho más.

En frío, visto desde fuera, parece que lo más lógico sea borrar la respuesta y dar paso a la buena. El hecho de haber recibido votos positivos suele arrastrar nuevos votos, por lo que no parece justo mantener un contenido totalmente diferente al que los obtuvo.

Ahora bien, en caliente, cuando uno acaba de escribir una respuesta y "lucha" por ser de ayuda, es complicado darle al botoncito de "eliminar" y dejarlo correr. Lo digo porque a mí mismo me ha pasado algunas veces y pasado el tiempo me he dado cuenta de que debí haber hecho esto pero no lo hice.

¿Qué hacer? Tal y como explica Marc en su respuesta, sé honesto contigo mismo y con la comunidad: ¿actualizas la respuesta porque te diste cuenta tú mismo de la manera correcta o porque viste de reojo la respuesta nueva que así lo indica? ¿Aporta tu respuesta alguna visión especialmente buena o es simplemente otra forma de contestar lo que dice la otra?

En base a esto, yo creo pues que hay distintas posibilidades:

- Eliminarla.
- Eliminarla y sugerir modificaciones complementarias (y útiles) a la nueva respuesta.
- Editarla para ofrecer información relevante que la otra respuesta no contenga.

Discusiones relevantes en inglés:

- [What is FGITW and SCITE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/209901): sobre la casuística de muchas respuestas parecidas apareciendo en el mismo momento. Para mí, el caso paradigmático en el que borrar la respuesta tiene sentido en lugar de mantener cinco versiones casi iguales.
- [An elegant solution for “answer-stealing” edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21643/209901): sobre cómo gestionar estas ediciones que "roban la respuesta".

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente pienso que la mejor forma de actuar es la de ser lo más honesto posible. SOes no es un juego donde se tenga que competir y por ello si alguien da una respuesta mejor que la tuya no es necesario competir con aquella respuesta. Si te das cuenta de que tu respuesta es mala la puedes editar, pero con el fin de ayudar al que pregunta no para ganar puntos. Y si entre tanto alguien dio una respuesta mejor a la tuya, pues no pasa nada. Deja tu respuesta ahí, que no pasa nada que haya respuestas que no le  sirven al que preguntó. El objetivo de SOes es ayudar a quien tiene problemas a resolverlos. Si alguien da una mejor respuesta y tu ves que es mejor que la tuya, lo honesto es darle puntos, pero no es obligatorio en SOes.

Comment: Solo para aclarar, no estoy simplemente hablando de que alguien dio una mejor respuesta. Estoy hablando de que el corregir tu respuesta resulta en duplicar la respuesta de otro. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo que aunque otro dé una mejor respuesta, si la tuya tiene algo diferente o un sabor diferente que aportar, pues vale la pena dejarlo. Pero eso no es lo mismo que duplicar la respuesta.

Comment: @sstan dudo que sea contenido duplicado. Y si realmente escriben lo mismo, sea en código, pueden diferenciarse en la explicación. Al ser la explicación diferente, se puede ver la calidad de la publicación. Creo que eliminar la publicación es una decisión personal, pero en mi caso no la eliminaría.

Comment: No me queda claro a qué te refieres con "Deja tu respuesta ahí" en el contexto en el que lo dices: ¿a editarla igualmente o a dejarla como estaba?